# In place works for int[] but not for int in java

Tags: java

The value of int a remains same after calling function (testInPlaceInteger(a)) but for int[] arr changes after calling the function (squareArrayInPlace). Why is int a value not changing?
Following is my code:

```
public class Test {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    int a = 5;
    int[] arr = new int[] {3, 4};

    Test test = new Test();

    test.testInPlaceInteger(a);
    test.squareArrayInPlace(arr);

    System.out.println(a);

    for (int i : arr) {
      System.out.println(i);
    }
  }

  public void testInPlaceInteger(int num) {
    num *= num;
  }

  public void squareArrayInPlace(int[] intArray) {
    for (int i = 0; i < intArray.length; i++) {
      intArray[i] *= intArray[i];
    }
  }
}
```

Output:

```
5
9
16
```

Comment: primitives are only pass by value

Comment: @PavneetSingh - That also applies for non-primitives too.

Comment: @StephenC yeah , but just to keep thing simple, object can maintain it's states and behavior throughout function calls whereas primitive can't :)

Comment: I know that.  But when you write that primitives are passed by value, some people would think that you are implying that reference types are not passed by value.

Answer (score 0):

Because `int` is a primitive type and is passed by value. However, `intArray[i]` is a memory location, so you can change the value within.